# What is "Disk Data (cached)" in the memory usage chart metrics of GCP compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a compute engine instance in Google Cloud Platform. I have monitoring agent installed on it. There is a memory part (Disk Data (cached)) shown in memory detail chart, that is using more than 50% of my total available memory.

May I know What is this Disk Data (cached) and why its taking that much of memory?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it's a Linux VM? That's just normal behavior of Linux to use spare memory for disk caching. It is unobtrusive.

See https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for an overview.

Also might be usefull - https://andythemoron.com/blog/2017-04-23/Understanding-Linux-Memory-Usage on how to check and interpret memory usage with `free` utility.

Comment: Yes, it is Linux VM.